# PHP & Google charts - Data from array changing when using require_once()

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

My problem is that, when i var_dump my array inside a separate file, the values are all correct, but when I require this file into another, in which i try using javascript with the rows i make, it returns me other values, and even erases parts of my array. Does someone know something about it? 
Here's the code i'm using to generate the chart in the separate file:

```
var_dump($jsRows_scatter);
?>
 <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'fixo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'fixo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'fixo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Afundamento');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Elevação');
    var foo = [<?php echo $jsRows_scatter; ?>];
      data.addRows(foo)
    var fool =[ <?php echo $jsRows_scatter1; ?>];
      data.addRows(fool);
    var fool1 =[ <?php echo $jsRows_1; ?>];
      data.addRows(fool1);  


            var options = {
          title: '',
          hAxis: {title: 'Duração (ciclos)', minValue: 0, maxValue: 10,
          logScale: 'true'
          },
          vAxis: {title: 'Intensidade (p.u)', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1},
          legend: 'none',
          pointSize: 5,
          colors:['red','#004411','green','#00FF00'],


              series: {
        // series 0 is the Scatter
        0: {
                lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 0

        },
        // series 1 is the Line
        1: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 0,


        }  
    }
        };


    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
} 
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: drawChart});
</script> 
<body>
<div id='chart_div' style="width:950px; height:300px;"></div>
</body>
```

and the `var_dump($jsRows_scatter)` returns me: `string(243) "[1.0199998,null,null,null,null,0.00589003],[0.6599999,null,null,null,null,0.00589003],[4.6799991,null,null,null,null,0.5],[0.2400000,null,null,null,null,0.5],[0.2400000,null,null,null,null,0.77272727],[0.1200000,null,null,null,null,0.77272727]"`
(which is ok).
So i use `require_once()` to call this array into a javascript google charts function whose code is:

```
function analise_desequilibrio(medicao, analise){
    var nome_analise='';
    switch(analise){
        case "unipede":
            nome_analise="Similaridade entre dias";
            document.getElementById("analises").innerHTML='<div id = "chart_div_carac_iec" style="width: 950px; text-align: center;">  </div>';
function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'fixo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'fixo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'fixo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Afundamento');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Elevação');
    var foo = [<?php echo $jsRows_scatter;?>];
      data.addRows(foo)
    var fool =[<?php echo $jsRows_scatter1;?>];
      data.addRows(fool);
    var fool1 =[<?php echo $jsRows_1;?>];
      data.addRows(fool1);  


            var options = {
          title: '',
          hAxis: {title: 'Duração (ciclos)', minValue: 0, maxValue: 10,
          logScale: 'true'
          },
          vAxis: {title: 'Intensidade (p.u)', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1},
          legend: 'none',
          pointSize: 5,
          colors:['red','#004411','green','#00FF00'],
              series: {
        // series 0 is the Scatter
        0: {
                lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 0

        },
        // series 1 is the Line
        1: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 0,
        }  
    }
        };


    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_carac_iec'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
} 
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: drawChart});


            break;
```

But, even before i reach the function with the steps on javascript, just as i use `require_once()` on this array file, my `var_dump` results: `string(74) "[3,null,null,null,null,2],[1,null,null,null,null,],[,null,null,null,null,]"` 
 Which means lots of data were deleted somehow. Does someone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get with a PHP file like this?  `<?php require_once('myscript.php'); var_dump($jsRows_scatter); ?>`  where `'myscript.php'` is the PHP file where you generate your data.  Make sure this test script contains no other code at all.  Also, it might help to revise your question to include the code from the script that generates the data.

Comment: @asgallant, I'm sorry for the late answer, i really needed to sleep. :) But i've tried that and it works fine, the array brings all the information as expected. And ok! I will edit again. Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, i've realized now it's the order in which i call the requires that is affecting, maybe some array name conflict, i'll try to solve this. But thanks anyways!